# How should I set the classpath of an HBASE so that it points to a zookeeper ensemble that is not managed by hbase?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

export HBASE_CLASSPATH=

any idea how to set this???

I tried like this but i am not sure whether its the right way or not..

export HBASE_CLASSPATH=$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/conf/zoo.cfg:$HBASE_CLASSPATH

Also I have one hmaster and 4 regionservers running on one vm and a zookeeper running on another.

but for the time being  to look whether both are working properly i am using master and one region server.

I was able to connect from zookeeper to hbase using zkCli.sh command and got the result as

[zkCli localhost:2181 connected [1]]

Currently I am not able to point hbase to zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

To point hbase to zookeeper which is not manged by hbase you need to set below properties

```
hbase-site.xml:
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>zookeeper host or IP</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>zookeeper port</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
</property>

hbase-env.sh:
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

This will create /hbase root node to manage tables on mentioned "zookeeper host or IP":"zookeeper port"

Hope this helps...